# cygwin git default web browser

Tags: browser, git, cygwin

I just installed git using cygwin. I then tried using git help status but I received the error fatal: '/usr/share/doc/git-doc': not a documentation directory. And indeed, there is no folder git-doc in /usr/share.

So I manually added the html folder in the right folder, and it now seems to work.
However, the default web browser that is used to display the page is a console one (w3m.exe).  I tried setting the value git config --global web.browser firefox, and even git config --global browser.firefox.path "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", but it doesn't work. What should I do to run the html with firefox (except using the file manager) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following:

```
git config --global web.browser cygstart
git config --global browser.cygstart.cmd cygstart
```

This will make `git` use the Windows default browser (which hopefully in your case is Firefox) and handle all necessary path conversions.  The `cygstart` command is part of the `cygutils` package.